# regex pattern for url validation to make http as required

Tags: regex, url

I'm stuck at regex pattern.
Currently I'm using regex:

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}
```

but it takes `www.google.co.in` as a valid url but I want `http://` or `https://` as a required part of url.
Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: you are using `|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,}` in alternation..it will obviously match `www.google.co.in`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.Now its working as per expectation after removing that.

Comment: @Learner if you use regex often you should try [this tool](https://regex101.com/)!

Comment: I will.Thanks for the link :)

Comment: `[(http(s)?):\/\/(www\.)?a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)`

above line (https://regexr.com/39nr7) taking mails without HTTP in it (eg gsp@gmail.com). Can anybody help me on this?